# How can I create this rising pitch?

Tags: pitch

to 4:50

Is this just a single note with a pitch modulation e.g. with an lfo?

How would the curve look like?

How is the last part different which sounds accelerated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of questions here:

> Is this just a single note with a pitch modulation e.g. with an lfo?

Looks like an arpeggiator with different notes.

> How would the curve look like?

If you are talking of the modulation (second part of the sound) , I would say a sineshaped LFO that modulate a parameter (which one I don't know, perhaps a wabetable)

> How is the last part different which sounds accelerated?

Well looks like the artist wanted to modulate his sound so he did it (but I'm not sure to well understand your question).

Comment: In t: at 4:42 the sound moves faster. So I was wondering if the note length is decreased there. But I don't know maybe its also some kind of modulation.

Comment: It looks like a pitch bend but I think it's probably more a modulation bringing out more and more high ends

Comment: Modulating the EQ, e.g. from band pass to a high pass shape?